# USB devices are not recognized unless I reboot or plug in the charger

Tags: usb, thinkpad

I am on Manjaro linux, kernel 5.4-rt, on a new Thinkpad x395 with a Ryzen 7 3700u. It does not recognize new usb devices unless you restart the whole system or plug in the charger, the charger can be removed prior to recognition. I am fairly certain this is an issue being a new machine. The bios was updated to 1.14 before I installed linux. I am curious as to whether this is a bios problem or if it is on the linux side, I would like to maybe do some troubleshooting steps to find out and try to work on a workaround.

I have limited knowledge on where to look here, but I have confirmed nothing even comes up in any directory under /dev when plugged in without the charger as well.

Comment: Sounds like a BIOS setting to preserve battery by not doing USB on battery, maybe.